# UITableView un-know click action behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm going through some stranger act of `UITableView` with the following functions, The problem is that the function is called without tapping on tableview cell. can anyone help me with this issue to fix.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: How are you trying to call the tap on call, right now?

Comment: We need more info to help you with this problem. `heightForRowAt indexPath` doesn't require you to tap a cell - this is called when the table is being populated.

Comment: @Grumme I'm not calling those functions neither with button action nor manually. Without doing it the tableview delegate object is triggering them.

Comment: Add a breakpoint into the method and check the callstack.

Comment: @Kerberos, Did that, it is showing from the thread com.apple.uikit.event fetch-thread. So i'm unable to understand why is that happening.

Comment: @JayachandraA Can you add an image of the stack please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got fixed as I deep dive in to debug the problem, there is a another View on top of the Tableview object with user interaction disabled so it was interacting with tableview selection.